# How to transfer time from one view controller to another?

Tags: swift

in my current project I have implemented a timer on one view.
When I click the button that leads to the next view, I want it to show the time the previous view had at the end.

This is my current code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var labelMinute: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelHour: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelSecond: UILabel!

weak var timer: Timer?
var startTime: Double = 0
var time: Double = 0
var elapsed: Double = 0
var status: Bool = false

var psgTextField: UITextField?
var emTextField: UITextField?


public var passengers2 = [""]

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return passengers2.count
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell2 = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell2")
    cell2.textLabel?.text = passengers2[indexPath.row]

    return (cell2)
}

@objc func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Do you really want to leave?",
                                                message: nil,
                                                preferredStyle: .alert)


        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Leave", style: .default, handler: { action in self.passengers2.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        } ))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true)


    }
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    startTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - elapsed
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    status = true

}

@objc func updateCounter() {

    // Calculate total time since timer started in seconds
    time = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startTime

    // Calculate minutes
    let minutes = UInt8(time / 60.0)
    time -= (TimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

    // Calculate seconds
    let hours = UInt8(time / 3600)
    time -= TimeInterval(hours)

    let seconds = UInt8(time)
    time -= TimeInterval(seconds)

    // Format time vars with leading zero
    let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
    let strHour = String(format: "%02d", hours)
    let strSecond = String(format: "%02d", seconds)

    // Add time vars to relevant labels
    labelMinute.text = strMinutes
    labelHour.text = strHour
    labelSecond.text = strSecond

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let thirdController = segue.destination as! ViewController3
    thirdController.timeHour.text = labelHour.text

    let fourthController = segue.destination as! ViewController3
    fourthController.timeMinute.text = labelMinute.text
}
}
```

Without the last "override" function, the timer on my first view works perfectly, but for some reason it won't transfer the time to the labels on my second view ("timeHour", "timeMinute").

Xcode gives me the error`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`, but the cases I found in the internet were different from mine.

Does someone know where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my thought:
1. Did you setup your segue correctly?
2. Passing data with segue, requiring you to pass the data and handle it correcly in the view event.

Some example code might look like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

        if (segue.identifier == "YourSegueIdentifier") {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! YourSegueViewController;

            destinationVC.passedData = "some-data-to-pass";
        }
    }
```

While on you receiving view controller, handle it on your viewDidLoad function, e.g

```
var passedData: String!;

func viewDidLoad() {
    self.txtName.text = passedData;
}
```

Comment: Hi Parama, I'm pretty sure that my segue is correct, at least without the last override function I can go to the second view without any problems, the time simply doesn't work then. I'll try your code out in a second, but isn't this more of a backup, so the app simply doesn't crashes in the worst case? I'm very new in programming, and still have to learn a lot

Comment: If you sure that your segue is correct, try to remove the UI accessing code as I suggested above, your receiving view controller is not ready yet.

Comment: Yea, I did as you suggested it in your example and now it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

First of all (and this is not the real problem, but I need to say it anyway), your code is riddled with exclamation marks. Any of them might cause a crash. Don't use exclamation marks! (Like that one.) Your `labelHour` could be `nil`. Your `labelMinute` could be `nil`. Your segue destination might not be a ViewController3. All of that code is very dangerous! You need to check all of those things safely, not use exclamation marks.

However, the real problem is this line:

```
thirdController.timeHour.text = // ...
```

Your `thirdController` has not yet loaded its view, so it has no `timeHour` label yet.

Your timing here is all off. But even worse, the whole spirit of that line is wrong; you must *never* interfere with another view controller's interface. You need *properties* in ViewController3 that you can set, and ViewController3 can pick up those values in its `viewDidLoad` and configure *its own interface*.

Comment: Hey, I think your advise is pretty much the same as Parama's and that was it, so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your outlets in the destination view controller haven't been connected yet when you try to access them.  Try adding this line of code:

```
thirdController.loadViewIfNeeded()
```

Below your existing line of code:

```
let thirdController = segue.destination as! ViewController3
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, sorry but I don't really get your idea. I already have a "let thirdController" and I can't declare it twice?

Comment: Hi Robin, the first line above is just there to show you where to add the second line. :)  Only add the line `thirdController.loadViewIfNeeded()`, below your existing line `let thirdController = segue.destination as! ViewController3`.  I updated t he answer to be more clear

Comment: That's bad advice. He should not be touching the destination view controller's outlets in the first place.

Comment: @matt, I don't disagree with your evaluation of the best way to encapsulate the destination view controller and pass data.  But I'm trying to answer this specific question, which is "why is this crashing / not working" without getting into discussions of architecture. There is nothing technically wrong / in violation of Apple documentation that I'm aware of by using public outlets, it's just not good architecture / encapsulation.

Comment: They declared it all in one ViewController in the Youtube tutorial I watched, so I thought it would be the right way. Anyway, thanks for your help too :)